# Get the Application Context In Fragment In Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have stored some data to a Global Class By using the Application Context In One Activity. Later I have to Retrieve those values in A Fragment. I have done something like this to store in Global Class.

```
AndroidGlobalClass  AGC = ((AndroidGlobalClass) getApplicationContext());
AGC.setUser_access("XYZ");
AGC.setFirst_name("ABC");
```

And In the Manifest I have done :

```
<application
    android:name=".AndroidGlobalClass"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
       android:name="abc.SignInActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now When I am Trying to Get the Application Context Using this... I am not getting the Context...

```
AndroidGlobalClass  AGC = ((AndroidGlobalClass) getApplicationContext());
```

This is My Fragment Activity

```
public class Fragment_NewsFeed extends Fragment {
    public Fragment_NewsFeed() {
    }

    RestImplimentationMethods RIM;
    AndroidGlobalClass AGC;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsfeed, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful asking for help "ASAP". You scare off anyone who might want to give you a nice thorough answer. As you've seen you end up w/ a bunch of one line answers that don't really help.

Comment: or use `isAdded()` to check weather fragment is attached to activity or not and if attached than u will able to get `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`  :). this way u insure, never get NPE error and app will not gonna crash

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can get the context using 
`getActivity().getApplicationContext();`

Comment: Careful where you're calling this, as `getActivity()` will return null if the fragment has been detached

Comment: Create a static application context in your Application class and assign it in onCreate(): 
MyApplication.sContext = getApplicationContext();
Then you can access it from any activity without worrying about fragment detachment.

Comment: No need to use .getApplicationContext(), just getActivity() is enough.

Comment: Only get `getApplicationContext()` when the object to which context has to be passed has a global context other wise be ready for OOM sooner or latter.

Comment: @Borzh getActivity() will not give you the application context and will lead to memory leaks with retained fragments after activity recreation. It is not advisable to use that context if you don't specifically need it. It is always better to call getApplicationContext() if that is sufficient.

Answer (score 21):

Use

> getActivity().getApplicationContext()

to obtain the context in any fragment

Comment: Careful, this only works if the fragment is currently attached to an activity!

Comment: @A.Steenbergen what is the case at which it is not attached?

Comment: @Sreekanth Karumanaghat This can happen when the screen is rotated. Check out the fragment lifecycle.

Comment: @A.Steenbergen My app is designed only for portrait, Is there any other case where this is applicable?

Comment: @Sreekanth Karumanaghat There might be in state restoration cases, please refer to the fragment lifecycle

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat, when you leave one fragment and move to other, `getActivity()` will be `null`. This may happen when a request returns a response after you exited the fragment.

Answer (score 15):

In **Kotlin** we can get application context in fragment using this

```
requireActivity().application
```

Comment: The problem is requireActivity could throw an exception, not sure you want to cope with that.

Answer (score 4):

you can define a global variable :

```
private Context globalContext = null;
```

and in the onCreate method, initialize it :

```
globalContext = this.getActivity();
```

And by that you can use the "globalContext" variable in all your fragment functions/methods.

Good luck.

Comment: When a fragment is detached, getActivity() returns null. A fragment is often detached during its own onCreate() while the activity is being recreated. This may crash with a NullPointerException after your app is pushed out of memory. Also, getActivity() does not return the application context. It requires another call to .getApplicationContext().

Comment: @colintheshots, could a fragment be actually detached during its own onCreate() if this fragment is created in the activity's onCreate()?

Comment: A fragment is typically attached during onCreate(). However, globalContext can later refer to an activity that no longer exists while detached or after being reattached. Also, it does not provide the Application Context, but the Activity context.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `getActivity();` This will solve your problem.

Comment: Can You Specifically write down the Code how to get the Application context for my Code.. I am having Problem with the code

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext(); Will be .. Thanx

Comment: AndroidGlobalClass  AGC = new AndroidGlobalClass  (getActivity());

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late response but you can do the following in Kotlin:

```
activity?.applicationContext?.let { SymptomsAdapters(it, param2, param3, ...) }
```

(?.) is for safe null operation to prevent from the null pointer exception.

You do not want to create a new context as that can lead to memory leaks when interchanging between fragments or when the device changes rotation.

And as someone mentioned above, in Java you can obtain context in a fragment by doing the following:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Support Library 27.1.0 and later, Google has introduced new methods `requireContext()` and `requireActivity()` methods.

Eg:`ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.soft_gray)`

More info [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-requireactivity-and-requirecontext-example-1c089ce11a3a)

Comment: This is a good answer, but if a fragment is detached, they still return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
private Context contextUApp;
```

...
OnCreate...

```
contextUApp = view.getContext();
```

or use

```
requireContext()
```

Comment: are you sure this return applicationContext not the activity context?

Comment: `requireContext()` gets the context that the activity is currently associated with, not the application context.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin Fragment, onViewCreated, use

```
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
```

> requireNotNull

is needed because the Fragment could be attached to a Context instead of a FragmentActivity. Alternatively, you could omit

> requireNotNull

but then the code become

```
        val application = (this.activity)?.application
```

and the next application call must be accompanied by, for example

```
val dummy = application?.let {.......}
```

where "...." is your code.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to onCreate

```
// Getting application context
        Context context = getActivity();
```

Comment: This is not the application context! Using this context with retained fragments across activity recreation will lead to memory leaks!