# Get context/activity in detached fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-context

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464273/get-the-application-context-in-fragment-in-android) where most answers advice to use `getActivity()` in order to obtain the context of a fragment, but how to get a reference to the activity/context if the fragment is detached (in which case, `getActivity()` returns null)?

My situation is that my fragment starts an AsyncTask which, on completion, calls the `onSuccess()` method of my fragment. But my fragment's `onSuccess()` method requires a context in order to show a Toast message or to access the shared preferences. So is there a reliable way of obtaining the context?

One way I'm considering is to pass a context object into my AsyncTask constructor, and pass it back out to my aforementioned `onSuccess()` callback method - but could this result in a memory leak?

(NB - There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/1617737) that shows how to retrieve the current activity but, again, it requires a valid context.)

Comment: did you try getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: onattach method is called first, in that you will get activity refrence, store it and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your fragment:

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
}
```

then use `context` where you want.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a chance of a memory leak with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the context after creating view, when you enter in fragment.

```
    Context context;

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
        MainView = rootView;
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        return rootView;
    }
```

use that context in your fragment, where ever you want.