# Get context from detached fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-context

I am trying to initialize a class `DataBaseHandler` derived from `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which takes `context` as a constructor value, from a detached fragment.
I've tried fixing it like the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808944/get-context-activity-in-detached-fragment) question suggests, however `override fun onAttach()` doesn't get called. My code:

```
class CustomFragment : Fragment() {

    /* first attempt to initialize DBHandler. I get an exception saying the fragment is not 
       attached to the context */
    private var db1: DataBaseHandler = DataBaseHandler(requireContext())

    // variables for second attempt to initialize DBHandler (after onAttach)
    private lateinit var fragmentContext: Context
    private lateinit var db2: DataBaseHandler

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        fragmentContext = context
    }
    
    // I get an exception, saying that context is not initialized
    db2 = DataBaseHandler(context)
    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `DatabaseHandler` inside the `onAttach()`

```
private lateinit var db2: DataBaseHandler

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    db2 = DataBaseHandler(context)
}
```