# how to set application context in a fragment in android?

Tags: android, list, fragment

i have an ActionBar that has 2 tabs and each tabs layout is a fragment. in 1 of these tabs , there is a listView. and i want to set ArrayAdapetr for it. but when i run app, error occurred and error is about my application context. my code is :

```
public class TarfandFrag extends Fragment {



String values[] = new String[]{"sadeq","ali"};
ListView listView;
Context context;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tarfad_layout,container,false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_tarfand);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

but its not working. notice that i don't want use listFragment or anything else. i replace context with getActivity() , context.getApplicationContext, getActivity.getApplicationContext. but not working. plz help meeeee

Comment: you are not setting you context, therefore it's null, (at least on the code you provided), can you post the right code, you mentionned using getActivity() , where did you use it

Comment: my problem is solved. from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464273/get-the-application-context-in-fragment-in-android

Comment: resolve : Context context = getActivity();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assing `getActivity()` to context in `onCreate`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=getActivity();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment, onCreate() is called before onCreateView(). the consequence of this is that, at the point onCreate() is called, your ListView is not yet associated with an element in the layout (as your are doing this in onCreateView() which gets called later) and will hence resolve to null and you will get a null pointer exception when you set the adapter for the ListView. Move the code setting the adapter to within the onCreateView() method and use getActivity() and you should be fine.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tarfad_layout,container,false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_tarfand);

    // Here listview will not be null as it is now bound to an object
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```