# Android Fragment onClick button open new Fragment with same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Activity which launches a Fragment called main page. This page has cards with buttons and each button opens a new fragment. The problem is that when it opens a new fragment it seems to start a new Activity, which is not the main one, launched at first. For this reason the toolbar I have on the main Page doesn't appear on other pages which are opened on the click from the Main fragment.

Does anybody knows how to make it not change the first Activity or at least how to access it from other fragments. When I try `getActivity()` or `getContext()` from these Fragments it is never the same Activity loaded initially.

Btw, the first Activity extends AppCompactActivity

```
AppActivity activity = (AppActivity) v.getContext();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_layout, myFragment).addToBackStack("string").commit();
```

(Appears in the main fragment on click)

Comment: please post your ccode

Comment: Unfortunately I cant post the whole code from other reasons but I can show what I have in the main fragment :

Comment: yeah show that your button click and your xml

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: show your mainactivity xml

Comment: Sorry Im not allowed to, but I think the question is clear

Comment: sorry !!! then cant help you out :)

Comment: thank you, but don't you have any hint ? the question why does it happen when you start a new fragment from another fragment ?

Comment: The problem is that when it opens a new fragment it seems to start a new Activity. Which activity its starting?? is it AppActivity?

Comment: Exactly!! So how can I prevent it form happenning?

Comment: Oh I think you pointed to something, So the main Activity is lunched from another Activity, lets say the Applications Activity is lunched from and Start Activity, but the fragments they start new Application activities...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code i hope this will solve your problem...

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      FragmentEntityManagementPage  fragmentEntitymanagementPage = new FragmentEntityManagementPage();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rl_container1, fragmentEntitymanagementPage);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("FragmentEntityManagementPage");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, What exactly is this fragmentEntitymanagementPage? Where can I find it in my code ?

Comment: It is your target fragment name or second fragment name where you want to share data after button click.

Comment: Thanks, So I did add this to my code :FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.drawer_layout, myFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("FragmentEntityManagementPage");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();   But the problem it is still connected to the Activity I create before but it its not the same Activity as I have on the Start...

Comment: Cause I have before this :                         AppActivity activity = (AppActivity) v.getContext();
The question how do I get the first Activity ?

Comment: The Problem I am not allowed to share it, but I can say that the AppACtivity has getApplicationContext() - MyApp context but the Fragment has AppACtivity context...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464273/get-the-application-context-in-fragment-in-android

Comment: Yeah I try to use getActivity() in the fragment but it is not the same as I do getActivity() in the AppActivity...